# How to read chat on the server in RCON

Tags: java, steam

I am new to working with RCON. I have such a problem: I know how to send commands (I sent a command and immediately received a response), but how then can I read the game chat inside?

What do I want?
I want to connect to the remote server and listen to its port WITHOUT sending commands.

Can you help with how to implement this?